# Dieudonne modules and Cartier-Dieudonne module of a formal group

Tags: formal-groups, formal-schemes, dieudonne

As far as I understand, there are Dieudonne modules defined through the homomorphisms to Witt covector scheme and Cartier-Dieudonne modules defined by curves. Am I right that the latter sometimes (for example, in Norman's "An algorithm for computing local moduli of abelian varieties") are called Dieudonne modules? Is it just a negligence or there is something behind it?